# Attatched Property as binding target doesn't update value

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to extend a wpf button with an "IsSelected" property. I created a dependency object with an attatched property looking like this:

```
class FormSelectorExtension : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(FormSelectorExtension),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(SelectionChanged)));

    public static bool GetIsSelected(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsSelected(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    private static void SelectionChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

The Buttons i want to attatch the property to are generated by an ItemsControl:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="frameSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FrameSelectors}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="150" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Button Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=CommandParameter}"
                 Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FrameSelectorStyle}" FontSize="28" local:FormSelectorExtension.IsSelected="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem now, is the binding of the "Selected" property of my view model to the attatched property. If i'm using a static value the "SelectionChanged" eventhandler of the attatched property gets called properly.

As soon as i put in the binding, nothing happens. (The initial value is set properly but changed are not recognized.)

Static value

```
local:FormSelectorExtension.IsSelected="True"
```

Binding

```
local:FormSelectorExtension.IsSelected="{Binding Path=Selected}"
```

The Code where i update my view model:

```
private void ActivateFrame(FormsFrame selectedFrame)
{
    ActiveFrame = selectedFrame;    

    foreach(var selector in FrameSelectors)
        selector.Selected = selector.DisplayName == selectedFrame.DisplayName;

    OnPropertyChanged("FrameSelectors");
    OnPropertyChanged("ActiveFrame");
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
public class ButtonData
{
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }
    public object CommandParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that FrameSelectors is a collection of `ButtonData` instances, you would have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the ButtonData class too:

```
public class ButtonData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

---

As a note, your FormSelectorExtension class does not need to be derived from DependencyObject. That is only necessary for regular dependency properties, but not for attached properties.